# Indices of boundary elements 3D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 65x76x100 3D-matrix, where each element contains a material type. I have assigned dynamics to each element, but the dynamics of the border elements (or boundary, or exterior, or perimeter, or how you want to call it) are incorrect and need to be removed. I require all the linear indices of the border elements, currently i do that like this (and it works):

```
    materials; % given 65x76x100 3D-matrix;
    [nxgrid, nygrid, nzgrid] = size(materials);
    n = nxgrid*nygrid*nzgrid;
    N2 = nxgrid*nygrid;
    borderIndices = zeros(n, 1); % initialize an oversized matrix that contains the border indices
        for l = 1:nzgrid % loop over zgrid
            for k = 1:nygrid % loop over ygrid
                for j = 1:nxgrid % loop over xgrid
                    if (j==1)||(j==nxgrid)||(k==1)||(k==nygrid)||(l==1)||(l==nzgrid)
                        i = (l-1)*N2 +(k-1)*nxgrid+j; % subscript to linear index
                        borderIndices(i) = i;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
```

Those nested for-loops seem a bit redundant to me though. Is there a more optimal/better/cleaner way to solve this?

Comment: Learn basic MATLAB  indexing. A cube has 6 sides. You can access 1 of them as `materials(1,:,:)` or a different one `materials(:,end,:)`. You can remove them as `materials(1,:,:)=[]` or replace their values as `materials(1,:,:)=0`. In MATLAB, there is hardly ever a reason to have 3 nested loops if you want to operate in a matrix

Comment: Yes of course, but i want to get the linear indices of those, just as i asked. Not what you did (simply removing the border elements). Again, maybe i am missing something obvious because i do not think it is a hard question. But i am a bit stuck at the moment and cannot find the solution. I know nested for loops are hardly ever needed, thats why i ask the question.

Comment: What do you need the indices for? In any case, use the same logic. One face will have i=1, all possible j and all possible k. You can build that with `meshgrid`. Each face index will require 2 lines of code, no loops. Still, it hints of bad methodology that you need the indices, and you can not fix whichever problem you have with indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily as follows:

1. Create a 3D array with `true` on the boundary and `false` otherwise, using [`or (|)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) with [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/).
2. Apply [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) with one output to get the linear indices of that.

```
indices = find([1; zeros(size(materials,1)-2,1); 1] | ...
               [1, zeros(1,size(materials,2)-2), 1] | ...
               reshape([1, zeros(1,size(materials,3)-2), 1], 1, 1, []));
```

If you want the result as in your code (with zeros between the indices):

```
indices_with_zeros(indices) = indices;
```